# OpenXml.Packaging MainDocumentPart does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml, asp.net-core-1.0

I am breaking my head for a long time now and couldn't find any relevant info here or google. I am developing in ASP.NET Core 1.0 so I use the OpenXml lib. I have the following code based on samples and tutorials:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace AutoDocumentation.Dll
{
    public class WriteToFile
    {
        // Path of the word doc.
        private const string wordFilePath = @"C:\file.docx";

        static WordprocessingDocument wpd = WordprocessingDocument.Create(wordFilePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
        MainDocumentPart mdp = wpd.MainDocumentPart;
        mdp.Document = new Document();
    }
}
```

The **problem** is that mdp.Document line throws the error

> "The name 'mdp' does not exist in the current context."

which is obviously not true. Can you suggest a turn around or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only declare and initialize fields in the class body, this line should be placed inside a constructor.